# $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ is an injective module over itself.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, injective-module

For any prime power $p^n$, prove that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n$ is an injective module over itself.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! I would suggest you to explain a little bit how you tried to solve it, so other people could help you better. Good luck!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

More generally, for any PID $R$ and every non-zero element $e \in R$, the ring $R/(e)$ is self-injective:

Baer's criterion implies that, if $S$ is a commutative ring in which every ideal is principal, an $S$-module $M$ is injective if and only if for all $a \in S$, $m \in M$ with $\mathrm{Ann}(a) \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(m)$ we have $m \in aM$.

This can be checked directly for $M=S=R/(e)$.

Comment: How do I check this directly?